# Need help using javascript to display a table and a description when I hover over an item

Tags: javascript, xml

My table prints out, but when I hover over an item, it won't print the description on 'area2'.
I want it to load the description from the xml file and print it according to the item I hover over.
e.g.: when I hover over a 'pine tree,' it would print something like 'Zone: Anywhere' 'Light: a lot' ' Price: cheap'

```
window.addEventListener("load", link_events, false); 

var xhr; 

function link_events() { 
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", showFile, false); 
    xhr.open("GET", "plants.xml"); 
    xhr.send(); 
} 
function showFile() {  
    var area1 = document.getElementById("area1");  
    var outstring = "<table><tr><th>Common Name</th><th>Botanical Name</th></tr>";  
    var i;  
    var plants;  
    var botanical;  
    var common;  

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {  
        if (xhr.status == 200) {  
            plants = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("PLANT");  
            for (i=0; i < plants.length; i++) {  
                common = plants[i].getElementsByTagName("COMMON")[0].firstChild.textContent;  
                botanical = plants[i].getElementsByTagName("BOTANICAL")[0].firstChild.textContent;  
                outstring += "<tr>" +  
                                "<div class=\"item\">" + "<td>"+common+"</td>"+ "</div>" +
                                "<div class=\"item\">" + "<td>"+botanical+"</td>"+ "</div>" + 
                             "</tr>";  
            }  

           outstring += "</table>";  
           area1.innerHTML = outstring;  
        }  
    } 

    var items = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    for (i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        items[i].onmouseover = GetFile;
    }
}  

function GetFile() {
    var area2 = document.getElementById("area2");  
    var zone;
    var light;  
    var price;
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", showFile, false);
        xhr.open("GET", "plants.xml", true);
        xhr.send(null);
    } else {
        area2.innerHTML = "XMLHttpRequest Failed.";
    }

    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {  
        if (xhr.status == 200) {  
            plants = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("PLANT");
            for (i=0; i < plants.length; i++) {  
                common = plants[i].getElementsByTagName("COMMON")[0].firstChild.textContent;  
                zone = plants[i].getElementsByTagName("ZONE")[0].firstChild.textContent;  
                light = plants[i].getElementsByTagName("LIGHT")[0].firstChild.textContent;  
                price = plants[i].getElementsByTagName("PRICE")[0].firstChild.textContent;
                area2.innerHTML = "<h2>" + common + "</h2>" + "<br />" + 
                                  "Zone: " + zone + "<br />" +
                                  "Light: " + light + "<br />" +
                                  "Price: " + price + "<br />";
            }  

        }  
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to request the same file (`plants.xml`) initially on page loading and then every time you hover over an item, that's just unnecessary.

Try this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', link_events, false);

var xhr;
var plants;

function link_events() {
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', showFile, false);
  xhr.open('GET', 'plants.xml');
  xhr.send();
}
function showFile() {
  var area1 = document.getElementById('area1');
  var outstring = '<table><tr><th>Common Name</th><th>Botanical Name</th></tr>';
  var i;
  var botanical;
  var common;

  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      plants = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('PLANT');
      for (i = 0; i < plants.length; i++) {
        common = plants[i].getElementsByTagName('COMMON')[0].firstChild
          .textContent;
        botanical = plants[i].getElementsByTagName('BOTANICAL')[0].firstChild
          .textContent;
        outstring +=
          '<tr>' +
          '<div class="item">' +
          '<td>' +
          common +
          '</td>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="item">' +
          '<td>' +
          botanical +
          '</td>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</tr>';
      }

      outstring += '</table>';
      area1.innerHTML = outstring;
    }
  }

  var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].onmouseover = getFile.bind(null, i);
  }
}

function getFile(index) {
  var area2 = document.getElementById('area2');
  var zone;
  var light;
  var price;
  common = plants[i].getElementsByTagName('COMMON')[index].firstChild
    .textContent;
  zone = plants[i].getElementsByTagName('ZONE')[index].firstChild.textContent;
  light = plants[i].getElementsByTagName('LIGHT')[index].firstChild.textContent;
  price = plants[i].getElementsByTagName('PRICE')[index].firstChild.textContent;
  area2.innerHTML =
    '<h2>' +
    common +
    '</h2>' +
    '<br />' +
    'Zone: ' +
    zone +
    '<br />' +
    'Light: ' +
    light +
    '<br />' +
    'Price: ' +
    price +
    '<br />';
}
```

Hope it works, I couldn't test it.